# css width on li inline not working

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the width of all the `<li>` elements 200px wide but it seems to be taking the exact width of the text.

```css
 #m_home_main_links li {
   display: inline;
   list-style-type: none;
   margin: 1%;
   text-align: center;
   background-color: orange;
   color: #198eff;
   width: 200px;
 }
```

```html
<div id="m_home_main_links">
  <ul>
    <a href="/">
      <li>mp3</li>
    </a>
    <a href="/">
      <li>videos</li>
    </a>
    <a href="/">
      <li>categories</li>
    </a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: make the li's display: block; and position: relative;

Comment: I need them displayed inline though

Comment: Like Novice said, your HTML is invalid.

Comment: `inline` elements don't respect _width_ settings. They are whatever width they need to be and, more importantly, they can _wrap_ to new lines, and setting a width makes no sense; they instead _respect_ the width of their container.

Answer (score 5):

You need to make `li` `display: inline-block` for them to respect width setting and still behave like inline element:

```css
#m_home_main_links li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 1%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: orange;
    color: #198eff;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: also if your going to use inline-block you should define vertical alignment

Answer (score 2):

first of all I would suggest you to place the anchor tag inside of the li tag instead of doing it the other way as it is not valid HTML.So it should look like

```
 <ul>
    <li><a href="/">mp3</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">videos</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">categories</a></li>
</ul>
```

For your width issue just remove the display inline from your class since you have made it an inline element it is not taking width.And if you want to place these li horizontally aligned you can use float left in your class.
This is the final css

```
#m_home_main_links li {
        float:left;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 1%;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: orange;
        color: #198eff;
        width: 200px;
    }
```

Comment: I would definitely use `inline-block` or `inline-flex` (depending) instead of `float`. Floating an element takes it out of the normal element flow so has other consequences, for example the _height_ of their container collapses. Of course there are reasons to use floats, but just making the list items horizontal is not a case where I would do that.

Comment: display:inline-block works well and consistently across all browsers, with a caveat for IE6/7, which support it for some elements.
For this reason I prefer float when you need other elements to flow around an elements,supports older version of IE.

Comment: Float is a terrible choice and is the incorrect rule for the desired outcome

Comment: Float might need you to write some extra markup to clean the floats. But everything has its pros and cons just depends on the context that you want to use it in. I see no harm in using float in this context.
I do have reasons for not using display:inline-block,one of them is it suffers from inherent whitespace, which will disturb your grid calculations , you can't make a two column grid with the left being 30% and the right being 70%, with display: inline-block, because the whitespace will break the grid and push the second column to the next line.

Comment: You should _not support_ IE 6. It is a Menace To Society. If ordered by management to support it you should quit your job immediately and find a sane workplace.  I personally have dropped IE 7 support and will soon be dropping IE 8. You may not park your dinosaur in my garage.

Comment: ... but I agree everything has its pros and cons, and that it depends on context. I just don't see _this_ as a place to use float.

Answer (score 0):

just, change `display: inline-block` and it will make keep inline and block your width li